# How do I change the header of a jQueryMobile multiple select dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

The documentation says - When a select is large enough to where the menu will open in a new page, the placeholder text is displayed in the button when no items are selected, **and the label text is displayed in the menu's header. This differs from smaller overlay menus where the placeholder text is displayed in both the button and the header, and from full-page single selects where the placeholder text is not used at all.**

I see 2 options here. 1, fix my code to where my label actually hides (I can't figure this out). or 2.  Make the multiple select box display the placeholder in the header instead of the label.

Thanks for your help.

Here is the code I'm using:
    `<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
    <label for="abc" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Select</label>
    <select name="abc" id="abc" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">
    <Option data-placeholder="true">Select Multiple</option>
    <Option>Option1</option>
    </select>
    </div>`